# Images on Google Drive not serving with HTML <img> Tag

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-api-python-client

I'm using Google Drive API v3 (python) and need to serve Drive objects to a browser, this was working for me using:

< img src = "[https://drive.google.com/file/d/#####*id*######&key=####](https://drive.google.com/file/d/#####_id_######&key=####) >

< img src = "[https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=#####*id*########&key=####](https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=#####_id_########&key=####) >

Currently (2016-11-13) not working. Getting a 404 error.

If url is pasted into the browser the image is displayed, if in html code image not displaying.

Thank you.

Comment: try links (src) directly in browser - maybe it shows HTML page with error message and more informations.

Comment: "Not working" isn't much of a problem report.  What is it doing?  Do you get an error?

Comment: and try when you logout from Google Drive - maybe it's private data and you can't see when you logout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display media files from Google Drive in the browser, you'll have to **use the web links** which is obtained by using 
[Files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#try-it). 
[image]

Gave the [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get#try-it) a run and got this link for `thumbnailLink`:

```
https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/2LRQM3FzopXEXogbArbNOnfQXI9eLOxR144aMVPQdydBeBxsD4FdP6L0upPOf2Chrd3Oug=s220
```

However, note that links like `webViewLink` may require you to be signed in to your Google account. The same concept applies to Python.

Comment: Yes, the thumbnailLink works great, but I tried webViewLink and it's not working, how would I display the full image? Thank you, Thank you